# Specifically 3rd and 5th navbar link is not set as 'active' when clicked on; unless you scroll up a little

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar, scrollspy

I am building my portfolio/resume website [www.ashutoshtripathy.com](http://www.ashutoshtripathy.com) which has shown some unusual issue. The 3rd link (li element) in navbar when clicked on, does not set itself as 'active'. Unless we scroll a little bit up, the colour of the nav icon does not change. This also happened for the 5th link but it was solved when I added a footer outside and below the 5th section. Don't know why!

I am using VanillaJS Scrollspy which does not seem to be a problem (I think!). Please look into the issue. Whole code is open source.
Go to link [www.ashutoshtripathy.com](http://www.ashutoshtripathy.com)

Github Link - https://github.com/Th3-M3nt0r/AshutoshTripathy

[Homepage view of my website (Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0Kn2.png)

Comment: Works fine for me!

Comment: @ed2 it works fine when viewed in 4k resolution. What are you using?

Comment: @ed2 try cliking the 3rd icon on navbar when you open the site. The color does not change to orange.

Comment: Still works fine, Safari 14.0.2 with a 27" (1920px) screen (not 4k).

Comment: @ed2 Okay, thanks for testing. It was some cache issue, may be.